# Handling type check in Gson with collection

Tags: java, collections, gson

Hi I am using Gson for Json parsing. Consider I am having two pojo classes as follows:

```
class Sample1{

}
class Sample2{

}
```

To auto parse my response I am sending these classes. It gives me compile time exception in following case:

```
public static Sample2 parseResponse(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, Sample1.class);
    // it gives me exception as I am sending Sample1 for parsing and returning as Sample2
}
```

But in case of collection it is not giving me that exception

```
public static ArrayList<Sample2> parseResponse(String jsonString) {
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Sample1>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
}
```

For above collection scenario it doesn't give any exception,as for collections I am passing it as *Type*. Is there any better way to handle it.

Comment: To complement your question: 
If I do this: ``Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Sample1>() {}.getType();`` I get any compile time exception, but I get during runtime an ``java.lang.ClassCastException``

Comment: This ``java.lang.ClassCastException`` happens in your method, because of ``gson.fromJson`` returns ``Sample1``

Answer (score 0):

The second example can be compiled because `Type` has no generic type parameter and therefore `Gson.fromJson(String, Type)` was implemented in a way that the generic type parameter used as return type is not bound.

You could however write an utility method yourself which takes a `TypeToken` instead of a `Type`:

```
public static <T> T fromJson(Gson gson, String json, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    return gson.fromJson(json, typeToken.getType());
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
fromJson(gson, json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Sample1>>(){})
```